# notnoop APNS 0.2.3 failing to send message

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I am using notnoop APNS 0.2.3, was struggling with the certs, and now I am struggling with SSL.

There is no documentation on how to prepare a p12 file for the library, so I found [this article](http://faq.appaloosa-store.com/knowledgebase/articles/61785-how-to-generate-apple-push-notification-p12-file-) to guide me.

```
service = APNS.newService() 
            .withCert(mycertPath, myP12password)
            .withSandboxDestination()
            .build();        
service.start();
service.testConnection();
service.push(listOfTokens,payload);
```

The start method fails with the following dump

```
09:46:16,657 INFO  ~ Failed to send message Message(Token=00; Payload=)... trying again after delay
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:58)
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:240)
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:230)
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.testConnection(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:294)
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.testConnection(ApnsServiceImpl.java:57)
```

Did I screw up the p12 file? Is there something else I am missing here?

[UPDATE 1]
I am trying the following script to create and test the p12 file command line, and am also getting a connection error, so there is something I likely messed up in the certificates.

[UPDATE 2]
I altered the script to create p12 files... incase others can benefit from this.

```
#!/bin/sh
bold=`tput bold`
normal=`tput sgr0`

# CONVERT CERT TO PEM
echo "${bold}CONVERTING${normal} APNS..."
openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out aps_development.pem
openssl x509 -in aps_production.cer -inform der -out aps_production.pem

# CONVERT PRIVATE KEY P12 INTO PEM
echo "${bold}CONVERTING ${normal} private key..."
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out my_private.pem -in my_private.p12

# COMBINE CERTS INTO SINGLE P12
echo "${bold}COMBINING ${normal} development..."
#cat aps_development.pem my_private.pem > my_development.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in aps_development.pem -inkey my_private.pem -out my_development.p12

# COMBINE CERTS INTO SINGLE P12
echo "${bold}COMBINING ${normal} production..."
#cat aps_production.pem my_private.pem > my_production.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in aps_production.pem -inkey my_private.pem -out my_production.p12

echo "${bold}TESTING${normal}..."

# TEST IT
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert aps_development.pem -key my_private.pem
```

Comment: Did you generate a sandbox certificate or a production one? From your code, it looks like you need a sandbox certificate. Are you sure you are using the correct password?

Comment: Hi Eran, you are correct. This is a sandbox cert that I created in Feb this year. I do not recall if I had a password to generate it with Apple or not. The private key I created through KeyStore has a password and I am confident I ended that correctly.

Comment: Oh that was dumb... I had completely forgotten the process that required the CSR to be uploaded to Apple in generating the APN cert. I had created a new one without telling Apple about it so they never matched.

Comment: It also helps to know that AdHoc distribution is considered production with APN.

Comment: So, did you get through the exception or still having problem with the handshake?

Comment: This is resolved. The handshake problem was the certs did not match and the next problem was the notification was not being received. Both issues are resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was a certificate problem and a misunderstanding that "AdHoc" only works with production push servers.